# fetch_all or fetch_assoc MySQLi statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

is it possible to use the `fetch_all()`, `fetch_assoc()` etc. from the the `MySQLi_Result` class with a prepared statement from the MySQLi_STMT class?

I've done it using the `query()` method in the Mysqli class (and by escaping trough `mysqli_real_escape_string()`), but not using statements with binding parameters.

I'm considering using PDO

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are using [**PDO**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you will not be using the [**`mysqli_*`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) function : **those are two different APIs**.

Using PDO, you'll be able to use the [**`PDOStatement->fetchAll`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method, if you want to fetch all results from a resultset.

Else, you'll have to use [**`PDOStatement->fetch`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), or any other `fetch*()` method, in a loop, to iterate over the resultset.

If using prepared statements with MySQLi, you will apparently not have an instance of [`MySQLi_Result`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) -- which means you'll have to work with [`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) over your resultset, looping by yourself.